# Android WebView use loadData show image failed

Tags: android, image, loaddata

I want to show a picture with this URL :

```
String htmlData=
"<Html><head></head><body><p style="text-align:center">
<img src="//img10.xxx.com/xxx.jpg" /><br/></p></body></html>";

mWebView.loadData(htmlData, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);
```

but it can't be shown.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Surely this is a case of bad quotes, non-escaped quotes and badly formatted tags - eg  head tag not closed, no opening body tag, img tag with quote before img, all html attribute quotes not escaped, to name but a few things wrong with the above

Comment: thanks,I corrected that

Answer (score 1):

You can try `loadDataWithBaseURL()`, supplying a URL with the proper scheme.

Otherwise, fix the HTML to provide a scheme on that `src` attribute. `loadData()` does not know what scheme to use for that protocol-relative URL.

Comment: thanks, it works when use loadDataWithBaseURL() with a   baseUrl startWith http